# In ubuntustudio, why is there a sleep infinity process?

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-studio

There's a service called user/session-monitor.service whose execstart is `/bin/sleep infinity`. What is this used for? sleep is used by bash scipts to slow processes in a while loop, giving a chance to the user to kill the process. But with this sleep infinity, a pkill -9 sleep will match. Also killing this process, for some reason, kills the current X session.

What is this service unit supposed to be doing?

Comment: Please provide release details.. are you talking about a *legacy* Ubuntu Studio with XFCE, or *modern* using KDE? or Ubuntu Studio loading on a pre-existing system?

Comment: It's ubuntustudio 20.04 LTS, which uses xfce i believe. The kde versions are 20.10. Well i'm really interested why this would cause the x user to get logged out.

Comment: The service unit is meant for ubuntu studio, so only those users have this running, but since it just sleeps to infinity with no other purpose, i'd like to know why it's there in the first place.